# luchos in aron when Pelishtim captured it

Tags: ark-aron-kodesh

I want to know if the luchos were inside the Aron when the Pelishtim captured it.
Rashi notes in Sefer Shmuel Aleph Chapter 4 that Shaul grabbed the luchos from Golias on the battlefield and fled with them.
Were the Pelishtim able to get hold of the luchos or was the Aron empty while it was in the land of the Pelishtim?

Comment: Radak:
וירץ איש בנימן. דרשו בו שהוא היה שאול בן קיש שחטף הלוחות מיד גלית הפלשתי וברח לו ורחוק הוא שהוציא אדם את הלוחות מהארון שהרי כמה נגעים וכמה רעות באו לפלשתים מקדושת הארון בהיותו בארץ פלשתים לבד כל שכן אם שלחו יד בו כי גם אנשי בית שמש שהיו ישראלים מתו כמה מהן כי ראו בארון ה':

Comment: If they'd been there, wouldn't the plishti faces have melted? :)